# Can GWT be compared to javascript based frameworks?

Tags: javascript, gwt, backbone.js

How does GWT compare (or can it be compared) to Javascript frameworks such as `backbone.js`, `angularJS`, `Ember`, `JQuery`, etc.? Do they aim to accomplish the same job, making them competitors, or can they be used together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no. While GWT's compiler is essentially a Java-to-Javascript converter, the benefits it offers far outweigh anything I've seen from any popular JS libraries.

Since GWT-based apps are written in Java, they gain many of the benefits thereof, such as being strongly typed and extremely easy to refactor. If something changes that affects another class, you know it immediately. And for those things that Java isn't great at, you can always use Javascript to handle the case with JSNI. Google has also provided a great plugin for Eclipse which allows you to debug your code like nothing I've ever seen of a JS library. Another benefit of this is that you write your client- and server-side code in the same language, and GWT does the heavy lifting of tying them together.

There are also the benefits of the automatic generation of multiple permutations. GWT kicks out a copy of your code that looks and behaves identically (inasmuch as is possible) on the most commonly used browsers. Your clients all see the same thing without you carrying the extra weight. You aren't responsible for writing endless lines of code to deal with those countless browser idiosyncrasies that have plagued web developers forever. While to some extent these things are handled by some JS libraries, GWT makes it completely effortless.

In my experience, the libraries you mentioned are all great in their own right, but simply can't provide the powerful debugging, portability, extensibility, maintainability and portability that GWT does right out of the box. GWT isn't really built to work with other libraries, and instead gives you the capacity to do (mostly) everything those libraries can without their help. (Of course that isn't to say that you *can't* use other libraries wherever you want...you can if you really feel the need to do so.)

So in my opinion, no, there is no competition. GWT is the figurative heavyweight champion in this arena.

Comment: +1 To echo the sentiment, GWT allows you to bring all your design patterns knowledge to the front-end. You can build holistic architectures with sophisticated inheritance and composition, events, etc. You can build layers of abstraction to hide tremendous amount of complexity. I chuckle at the endless number of MVC-javascript frameworks being released. I can run laps around those for a complex system using GWT.